# Finding friction on a banked road

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

> **Problem**: A turn of radius $20m$ is banked for the vehicle of mass $200kg$ going at a speed of $10ms^{-1}$. Find the direction and magnitude of frictional force acting on a vehicle if it moves with a speed of $15ms^{-1}$.

[image: Banking of road problem]

**My attempt**:

For the optimum velocity of banking, friction will not act as horizontal component of normal reaction provides the necessary centripetal force. Therefore,
$$
\frac{mv^2}{R} = F_N\sin\theta, \ F_N\cos\theta = mg\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
$$
\therefore \frac{mv^2}{R} = mg\tan\theta\\
\therefore \tan\theta = \frac{v^2}{Rg} =\frac{100}{20\times10} =0.5\\
F_N \stackrel{\eqref{1}}= 1000\sqrt{5} \ N 
$$

---

[image: Slipping case in banked road]

Now, when we drive too fast, the car will tend to slip radially outwards. Hence, friction will act radially inwards. Therefore, to find the magnitude of frictional force, we have two ways:

> Either, solve the horizontal components or solve the vertical components
> **Note**: magnitude of *Normal reaction* will remain unchanged.

**Method 1**:
$$
F_N\sin\theta + F_f\cos\theta = \frac{mv^2}{R}\\
\therefore F_f = \frac{\frac{200 \times 225}{20} - 1000\sqrt{5} \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}} = 625\sqrt{5} \ N
$$

**Method 2**:
$$
F_f\sin\theta = F_N\cos\theta - mg\\
\therefore F_f = \frac{1000\sqrt{5} \times \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} - 200 \times 10}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}} = 0 \ N
$$

As we can see, the answers from the two methods are different. So, possibly I'm missing something. Can I get some hint?

Comment: *Note: magnitude of Normal reaction will remain unchanged.* This is your error. The normal force will be different from the value you calculate initially. Take your two equations at the end, which are both valid, and solve for $F_f$ by eliminating $F_N$

Comment: @AaronStevens: Okay, I understood what you've said. But, if I resolve the forces parallel to the normal reaction. Then, I get $F_N = mg\cos\theta$ in both the situation (i.e., when v = 10 and v = 15). Isn't it?

Comment: No, $F_N\neq mg\cos\theta$ There is an acceleration component perpendicular to the incline here

Comment: Oh! It seems I missed out the centrifugal force in the second scenario. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Yes, the acceleration is centripetal, hence you have centripetal force components

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.